# Convert dataframe to 3D array

Tags: arrays, r

I need to convert a dataframe to an array of 3 dimensions.  All columns in the dataframe are numeric.  What is an elegant and/or efficient way to accomplish this?

Example:

```
x <- 1:3
y <- 1:3

g <- t(vapply(x, function(x){ 
      vapply(y, function(y){ 
          as.numeric(paste(x,y,sep="."))}, numeric(1))}, numeric(3)))

gdf <- data.frame( cbind(rep(1:3,each=3), rbind(g, g*2, g*3)) )
```

I want to convert "gdf" to an array where gdf$x1 defines the third dimension.  The result would look like this:

```
ga <- array( c(g, g*2, g*3), dim=c(3,3,3) )
```

Thanks!

Comment: There is no such thing as a 3d dataframe. (You could of course normalize the datastructure but that is what you are asking us _not_ to do.  If you want an R array then please do not consider using `$` as an an extraction operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also found this way using the package abind:

```
abind( split(gdf, gdf$X1), along=3)
```

Answer (score 2):

This works with your example, I hope it will be general enough for you:

```
gb <- aperm(array(unlist(gdf[, -1]), c(3, 3, 3)), c(1, 3, 2))

identical(ga, gb)
# [1] TRUE
```